# JS, strange override behaviour

Tags: javascript, loops

I receive a **data** in the format:

```
data = [
  {
    name: 'example1',
    options: {
      'label1': {
        param2: 'hey'
      },
      'label2': {
        param2: 'hey2'
      }
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Then, I use the following operation:

```
  let repos = [];
  data.map(repo => {
    Object.keys(repo.options).map(k => {
      repos.push(Object.assign(repo, {
        param1: k,
        param2: options[k].param2
      }));
    });
  });
```

I would expect that the code above produces

```
repos = [
  {
    name: 'exmaple1',
    param1: 'label1',
    param2: 'hey'
  },
  {
    name: 'exmaple1',
    param1: 'label2',
    param2: 'hey2'
  },
  ...
]
```

However, it produces

```
repos = [
  {
    name: 'exmaple1',
    param1: 'label1',
    param2: 'hey'
  },
  {
    name: 'exmaple1',
    param1: 'label1',
    param2: 'hey'
  },
  ...
]
```

and I have no idea why. For some reason, the last loop over the keys overrides param1 and param2 in all previous iterations. Any idea how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `Object.assign(repo` do `Object.assign({}, repo`

Comment: Genius, I didn't think of reordering the assignment...

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do:

```
repos.push({
   name: repo.name,
   param1: k,
   param2: repo.options[k].param2
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
data = [{
  name: 'example1',
  options: {
    'label1': {
      param2: 'hey'
    },
    'label2': {
      param2: 'hey2'
    }
  }
}]

let repos = [];
data.map(repo => {
  Object.keys(repo.options).map(k => {
      repos.push({
        name: repo.name,
        param1: k,
        param2: repo.options[k].param2
      });
  });
});

console.log(repos);
```